# Cannot create a folder in Iphone but works in simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have something like this in my code

```
if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:uploadDirPath withIntermediateDirectories:true attributes:nil error:nil]) {
            HTTPLogError(@"Could not create directory at path: %@", uploadDirPath);
        }
```

The contents of `uploadDirPath` is this :

```
/Users/UserJ/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/535C67AB-F932-417B-8CC3-9A813F4F402C/data/Containers/Data/Application/347FA1B2-F790-46A6-B0D6-B638CF2F43F0/Music/
```

The above code works fine in the simulator but when I run it in my phone it gets into the condition saying it cant create the folder.

The content of the string when it shows up on my phone is

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3E115818-0619-46B0-BD13-BD35EFDF50E3/Music/
```

Any suggestions on why it cant create the folder on my phone ?

**Update:**

This is the code that comes before

```
NSArray* dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSMusicDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* MusicDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

//------
MultipartMessageHeaderField* disposition = [header.fields objectForKey:@"Content-Disposition"];
NSString* filename = [[disposition.params objectForKey:@"filename"] lastPathComponent];
//--------

if ( (nil == filename) || [filename isEqualToString: @""] ) {
    // it's either not a file part, or
    // an empty form sent. we won't handle it.
    return;
}    
//NSString* uploadDirPath = [[config documentRoot] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"upload"];
NSString* uploadDirPath = [MusicDir stringByAppendingString:@"/"];


BOOL isDir = YES;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:uploadDirPath isDirectory:&isDir ]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager]createDirectoryAtPath:uploadDirPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
}

NSString* filePath = [uploadDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent: filename];
if( [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath] )
{
    //Delete this file if it exists
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
}
```

I noticed that the array when run on Iphone is empty but when it runs on simulator its fine

```
NSArray* dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSMusicDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

Comment: 1) Update your question with the code used to create `uploadDirPath`. 2) Use the `error:` parameter of `createDirectoryAtPath` so you can see why it failed.

Comment: Nitpick - Pass `YES`, not `true` for `BOOL` parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe since application in iOS device runs in sandbox manner, AppData folder structure is predefined. Please try creating your Music directory inside Documents directory and it should work:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirPath = paths.firstObject;
NSString *uploadDirPath = [documentsDirPath  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Music"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:uploadDirPath withIntermediateDirectories:true attributes:nil error:nil]) {
    HTTPLogError(@"Could not create directory at path: %@", uploadDirPath);
}
```